# React Redux implementation with React Hooks -> How to use useDispatch with type-checking?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I have some question about the type-save implementation of Redux in a Typescript React App.

I have done Setup and type-checking on Reducer and also using useTypedSelector from react-redux. Here, only one thing that i have inside the case Statements of Reducer a loose type-checking but that's not so problematically.

My Setup of the Redux Store:

```
// --------------------------------------- REDUX STORE ---------------------------------------
interface ITimePreset {
  session: number;
  break: number;
}

const UPDATE_TIMEPRESET = 'UPDATE_TIMEPRESET';
const INCREMENT_TIMEPRESET = 'INCREMENT_TIMEPRESET';
const DECREMENT_TIMEPRESET = 'DECREMENT_TIMEPRESET';
const BREAK = 'break';
const SESSION = 'session';

type Item = typeof BREAK | typeof SESSION;

interface IUpdateTimepresetAction {
  type: typeof UPDATE_TIMEPRESET;
  payload: {
    value: number;
    item: Item;
  };
}

interface IIncrementTimepresetAction {
  type: typeof INCREMENT_TIMEPRESET;
  payload: Item;
}

interface IDecrementTimepresetAction {
  type: typeof DECREMENT_TIMEPRESET;
  payload: Item;
}

type TimePresetActionTypes = IUpdateTimepresetAction | IIncrementTimepresetAction | IDecrementTimepresetAction;

const initialState: ITimePreset = {
  session: 25,
  break: 5,
};

const timePresetReducer = (state: ITimePreset = initialState, action: TimePresetActionTypes): ITimePreset => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_TIMEPRESET:
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.payload.item]: action.payload.value,
      };
    case INCREMENT_TIMEPRESET:
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.payload]: state[action.payload] + 1,
      };
    case DECREMENT_TIMEPRESET:
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.payload]: state[action.payload] - 1,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  timePreset: timePresetReducer,
});

type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>;

const useTypedSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector;

const store = createStore(rootReducer);
```

Usage of the useTypedSelector with nice type-checking is pretty fine:

```
const timePreset: ITimePreset = useTypedSelector(state => state.timePreset);
```

But for useDispatch i doesn't found a Solution for type-checking:

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();

// This is the correct one:
dispatch({ type: DECREMENT_TIMEPRESET, payload: element });

// Wrong one with no error
dispatch({ type: 'Whaaat', payload: 9 });
```

Is there a way for a type-checking on useDispatch Parameters?
Did you have other suggestions for Implementation of Redux Store (Some best Practices)-> This is my very first Example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few things which should help you here.

1. One global **ActionType** type for all action types in the system.

```
type ActionType = 'UPDATE_TIMEPRESET' | 'INCREMENT_TIMEPRESET' | 'DECREMENT_TIMEPRESET';
```

Of course specific type can be important from modules, you don't need to have them in one place but for example

```
import SomethingActionType from 'someModule';
import Something2ActionType from 'someModule2';
type ActionType = SomethingActionType | Something2ActionType;
```

2. Define **Action** type

We need to have one general definition of how our `Action` looks like. Example type:

```
type Action<P> = {
  type: ActionType,
  payload: P
}
```

Our `Action` is type constructor, we can now define specific types like `Action<string>` or `Action<UserRequest>`

3. Define **ActionCreator** type

Next step is to define ActionCreator type. ActionCreator is just simple function which return a valid Action.

```
type ActionCreator<P> = (p: P) => Action<P>;
```

4. Join these concepts to create some action creators

```
const incrementTimePreset: ActionCreator<Item> = payload => ({
   type: 'INCREMENT_TIMEPRESET' // type safe as it goes from ActionType union
   payload
})

const decrementTimePreset: ActionCreator<Item> = payload => ({
   type: 'DECREMENT_TIMEPRESET' // type safe as it goes from ActionType union
   payload
})
```

5. Using with useDispatch

Now istead of manual using `useDispatch` with some object literals ad hok, we will use action creators.

```
dispatch(decrementTimePreset(item))
```

6. Custom hook only for our actions, optionally as previous steps are good enough

```
const useSafeDispatch = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  return <P>(action: Action<P>) => dispatch(action);
}

// using
const dispatch = useSafeDispatch();
dispatch(decrementTimePreset(item)); // only proper action structure is allowed
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this Step by Step Guide ... Already at Step 5 all works like I expected :-) ... But i doesn´t understand Step 6 i think there is something missing ... Maybe you can check and explain me how it works?

Comment: Removed one typo check again please

Comment: Found the Problem ... implementation of useSafeDispatch not working in .tsx file -> Compiler Error while the Generics are interpreted as JSX Tags ... Tooo long Day.....